# How to fix a Google Maps Error with EAS build on iPhone?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, node-modules, react-native-maps

I migrated my Expo SDK 43 Managed Workflow project to an EAS Build.

I use Google Maps as my default map choice for Android and iOS, but I when navigating to a screen with a map I receive this error:

```
react-native-maps: AirGoogleMaps dir must be added to your xCode project to support GoogleMaps
 on iOS. at node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/components/decorateMapComponent.js:27:54 in <anonymous>
```

When I follow the path laid out in the error to my node_modules file, it takes me to "decorateMapComponent.js" which is a js file that contains the code below.

What needs to be modified to make the EAS on iOS accept Google Maps?

Below is the code:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { requireNativeComponent, NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { PROVIDER_DEFAULT, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from './ProviderConstants';

export const SUPPORTED = 'SUPPORTED';
export const USES_DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATION = 'USES_DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATION';
export const NOT_SUPPORTED = 'NOT_SUPPORTED';

export function getAirMapName(provider) {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    return 'AIRMap';
  }
  if (provider === PROVIDER_GOOGLE) {
    return 'AIRGoogleMap';
  }
  return 'AIRMap';
}

function getAirComponentName(provider, component) {
  return `${getAirMapName(provider)}${component}`;
}

export const contextTypes = {
  provider: PropTypes.string,
};

export const createNotSupportedComponent = message => () => {
  console.error(message);
  return null;
};

function getViewManagerConfig(viewManagerName) {
  const UIManager = NativeModules.UIManager;
  if (!UIManager.getViewManagerConfig) {
    // RN < 0.58
    return UIManager[viewManagerName];
  }
  // RN >= 0.58
  return UIManager.getViewManagerConfig(viewManagerName);
}

export const googleMapIsInstalled = !!getViewManagerConfig(
  getAirMapName(PROVIDER_GOOGLE)
);

export default function decorateMapComponent(
  Component,
  { componentType, providers }
) {
  const components = {};

  const getDefaultComponent = () =>
    requireNativeComponent(getAirComponentName(null, componentType), Component);

  Component.contextTypes = contextTypes;

  Component.prototype.getAirComponent = function getAirComponent() {
    const provider = this.context.provider || PROVIDER_DEFAULT;
    if (components[provider]) {
      return components[provider];
    }

    if (provider === PROVIDER_DEFAULT) {
      components[PROVIDER_DEFAULT] = getDefaultComponent();
      return components[PROVIDER_DEFAULT];
    }

    const providerInfo = providers[provider];
    const platformSupport = providerInfo[Platform.OS];
    const componentName = getAirComponentName(provider, componentType);
    if (platformSupport === NOT_SUPPORTED) {
      components[provider] = createNotSupportedComponent(
        `react-native-maps: ${componentName} is not supported on ${Platform.OS}`
      );
    } else if (platformSupport === SUPPORTED) {
      if (
        provider !== PROVIDER_GOOGLE ||
        (Platform.OS === 'ios' && googleMapIsInstalled)
      ) {
        components[provider] = requireNativeComponent(componentName, Component);
      }
    } else {
      // (platformSupport === USES_DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATION)
      if (!components[PROVIDER_DEFAULT]) {
        components[PROVIDER_DEFAULT] = getDefaultComponent();
      }
      components[provider] = components[PROVIDER_DEFAULT];
    }

    return components[provider];
  };

  Component.prototype.getUIManagerCommand = function getUIManagerCommand(name) {
    const componentName = getAirComponentName(
      this.context.provider,
      componentType
    );
    return getViewManagerConfig(componentName).Commands[name];
  };

  Component.prototype.getMapManagerCommand = function getMapManagerCommand(
    name
  ) {
    const airComponentName = `${getAirComponentName(
      this.context.provider,
      componentType
    )}Manager`;
    return NativeModules[airComponentName][name];
  };

  return Component;
}
```

Comment: Try this https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/693#issuecomment-262656417

Comment: @ErikMazzelli I don't have native cocoa pods that I can install like so; my project is originally Expo Managed Workflow

Answer (score 0):

try adding "expoCli": "4.13.0", to your eas.json like this:

```
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.41.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "base": {
      "expoCli": "4.13.0",
    },
    "simulator": {
      "extends": "base",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "development": {
      "extends": "base",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "extends": "base",
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "extends": "base",
      "releaseChannel": "production"
    }
  },
  "submit": {
  }
}
```

Had same issue, did work for me.

Comment: So sorry for the delay in my reply. It turns out that I had to add an API key for iOS devices themselves, but I am unable to load the maps on Android. Any thoughts on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Check that you have `ios.config.googleMapsApiKey` set (with a valid API key for iOS). This was confusing because for android it's `android.config.googleMaps.apiKey`.

The full details on how to get API keys for Google Maps and how to configure EAS are at https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/#ios.

**Longer answer w/ debugging steps:**

I was getting this error after having correctly set up Google Maps on Android.

I copied the same config block in `app.json`, and was confused about why the error was happening until I checked the logs for the "Run expo doctor" step on the Expo site for my dev build.

It showed:

```
 • Field: ios/config - should NOT have additional property 'googleMaps'.
```

I had copied over the android config, so for iOS it was essentially not seeing the key at the correct location (`ios.config.googleMapsApiKey`) and giving me an error because of that.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and followed the installation steps from the **react-native-maps** documentation. To resolve the problem of generating the iOS folder and configuring the Google Maps API key, here's what worked for me.
1 Run the following command to generate the iOS folder **npx expo prebuild** and
[click here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/HEAD/docs/installation.md) to see more.